# If $f$ is integrable, how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\lambda(\{\lvert f\rvert\ge 2^n\})<\infty$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I want to show the following converse of an (apparently) common integration theory exercise.

Suppose $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb R$ is integrable, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\lambda(\{\lvert f\rvert\ge 2^n\})<\infty.$$

Since series convergence is annoying to prove, I thought the best way to tackle this problem would be by assuming that the series doesn't converge, then showing that $f$ can't be integrable. However, I couldn't get much from the series not converging, as the terms of the series might well go to $0$ even if the series doesn't converge.

Is there something I'm missing to make this approach work? Or is a direct proof easier somehow?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proving $f$ is $L^1$ implies convergence of $\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}{ 2^k*m(|f| > 2^k)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1593616/proving-f-is-l1-implies-convergence-of-sum-k-in-mathbbz-2kmf)

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n=\sum_{n=1}^{n=N}2^n\lambda(\{|f|\geq 2^n\}$$f_n\leq |f|$ and is measurable implies that $\mu(f_n)\leq \mu(|f)$. The sequence $\mu(f_n)$ is a bounded increasing sequence, it converges.